# Android set multiple orientation programmatically

Tags: android, orientation

I try to set multiple orientation programmatically. For example I want to screen orientation can be Portrait, Reverse Portrait and Reverse Landscape.

I try to use this code but it seems like it didn't work.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
```

**EDIT**

setRequestedOrientation method applies to latest orientation. I just try to find a way to set two orientation.

Comment: Explain more. when you are using multiple orientaion?

Comment: I'm developing library for my company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set requested orientation based on configuration changes

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    } else if...
}
```

If you want to support portrait and reverse portrait together, do it with `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT` (more [info](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen)).
Another useful [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

**Edited:**

I don't see a case where would you need to request both landscape and portrait when new configuration is e.g. landscape, but you can try with `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT | ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

Comment: I know that If i want to set reverse and normal portrait, I can use Sensor Portrait but what If I want to use both sensor portrait and normal landscape? So what if I want my activity can change orientation to 0, 90 and 180 degree ?

Comment: Once again, I am not sure why would you do that, but you can always try with bitwise OR.

Comment: I just need this. I want to my activity can oriented to 0,90 and 180 degrees for example. Bitwise or didn't worked also.